# Problem with \psframe

Tags: pstricks

I want to create a book cover and for a start I want to add color to my page.

The problem is that when I add the given geometry page and write down the `\psframe`, the result I get is a page with colour on some of it, that means, 3/4 of the page is colored and some left blank. Can you help me fix it?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=36cm,paperheight=24cm,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\psset{unit=1cm}

\begin{pspicture}(36cm,24cm)

\psset{fillstyle=gradient,linestyle=none,gradbegin=blue,
gradend=yellow,gradangle=45,gradlines=1048}
\psframe(0,0)(36,24)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here, if I convert the ps to pdf using `dvips` and `ps2pdf`and view it, everything is quite fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pspicture` environment sets a block of given dimensions, very similar to what a single letter would do (in this case, just a very big character of width `36cm` and height `24cm`). So, similar to a single letter starting a paragraph that has a given `\parindent`, your `pspicture` does the same. Therefore, add

```
\noindent
```

before your `pspicture` environment so there is no indent set. Alternatively, add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to your preamble for a global removal of the paragraph indent. Since [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) has `margin`s set to `0cm`, the size of the `pspicture` should fill the entire page.

Comment: Thank you so much both for your answers.

Everything now works!